# SQL - don't display row when two criteria are met

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

At first I thought I could accomplish this in the `WHERE` clause of my query and using a `CASE` (see below) but I'm having some trouble getting the result I need. This query is to get product info for clients in a database. I need to not return rows at all if a certain product is ordered by a certain client. The problem is if I remove the product, then any other client with that product will show up as any client can order this product. I'm stumped on how to accomplish this.

```
Select
   OrderNumber, Client, Product From Orders
WHERE
  Product not in(CASE WHEN client = 'client_a' and product = 'product_1' THEN Product   END)
```

Hoping to see something like this as a result, the point being to show product_1 for all clients except client_a:

```
ordernumber client          product
123         client a    product 2
456         client b    product 1
789         client b    product 2
```

Comment: what output are you getting?

Comment: basically the same as above but add a line that shows client a with product 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the way `NOT IN` works. If any of the values in the list are NULL then it will return no results. e.g.

```
SELECT  [TestColumn] = 3
WHERE   3 NOT IN (1, 2, NULL)
```

Will return no results, and not 3.

If you expand the example into the equivalent OR statement you will see why:

```
WHERE   3 != 1
AND     3 != 2
AND     3 != NULL
```

Since `3 != NULL` Evaluates to false since nothing equals NULL the statement returns false.

You can accomplish the required result in 3 ways.

1) Use `ELSE` in your case statement to ensure no `NULL` results

```
SELECT  OrderNumber, Client, Product
FROM    Orders
WHERE    Product not in(CASE WHEN client = 'client_a' and product = 'product_1' THEN Product ELSE '' END)
```

2) Change `IN` to not equal, since your case statement will only return 1 value anyway

```
SELECT  OrderNumber, Client, Product 
FROM    Orders
WHERE   Product != (CASE WHEN client = 'client_a' and product = 'product_1' THEN Product END)
```

3) Revise your logic, this can be rewritten as

```
SELECT  OrderNumber, Client, Product 
FROM    Orders
WHERE   NOT (Product = 'product_1' AND Client = 'Client_a')
```

Comment: i see the logic behind all of this, but its not working for my query.  obviously i posted a generic query so its probably something in my query. ill see if i can work it out, otherwise ill post an edit

Comment: nevermind, was a number off by 1 digit in my query, this worked wonders, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you over complicating something very simple, don't you just want:

```
SELECT
   OrderNumber, Client, Product 
FROM Orders
WHERE Product != 'product_1' 
  AND client = 'client_a'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT OrderNumber, Client, Product
FROM Orders
WHERE Client <> 'client_a' OR Product <> 'product_1'
```

Or, semantically equivalent and maybe a little easier to see why this works:

```
SELECT OrderNumber, Client, Product
FROM Orders
WHERE NOT (Client = 'client_a' AND Product = 'product_1')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT OrderNumber, Client, Product
FROM Orders
WHERE Client != 'client_a' 
OR Product != 'product_1'
;
```